# Pasar por parametro una URL a mis Routes

Tags: angular7, angular-router

Aquí tengo mi ruta

```
{
        path: "flowcal-cameyo",
        component: AppLoadingComponent,
        resolve: {
            url: 'externalUrlRedirectResolver'
        },
        data: {
            externalUrl: vFlowcal
        } 
}
```

Teniendo en cuenta que mi modulo de rutas se arma al iniciar la aplicación y la URL me llega después de hacer login, como puedo inyectar la URL a la variable `externalUrl`

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio. Qué es lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Hola, he intentado setear la url en un localstorage y obtenerlo en el app.routing.ts pero la primera vez llega en null, a la segunda ya se obtiene la ruta de manera adecuada